# How can I update timestamp on each request in PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I can use Server[request_time] to get current timestamp. But how would I use this on each request so that I know which session hasn't been active for more than 10 minutes? Basically I do not know how to detect these requests so that I can capture the last timestamp(based on that request). Does it have to be attached to every single html button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the time of the last request in the session:

```
$_SESSION['last_request'] = time();
```

You do this on every request.

**Before** you update the session value, you can check how long the session was inactive:

```
if (time() - $_SESSION['last_request'] > 10*60) {
    echo 'You were inactive for at least 10 minutes.';
}
```

PS: You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` instead of `time()` if you have very long running scrips. In most scenarios it will make no difference.

Comment: Greetings, when you say on every request does it have to be a page refresh? so I would include a onload javascript call to lets say updatestate.php on every single page? Thank you!

Comment: @Marin         it doesn't matter. As soon as browser submits cookie with php session id with every request.